Let $S = \{ 1 , 2 , 3 ,\dots,100\} $, then number of non-empty subsets A of S such that the product of elements in A is even is :
I know my solution's wrong but I am not sure what in it is
My solution :
To find the number of non-empty subsets $A$ of set $S$ such that the product of elements in $A$ is even, we utilize the following approach:
Choose one even number from the set of even numbers, which can be done in $^{50}C_1$ ways.
Choose any additional numbers (whether even or odd) from the remaining numbers, which can be done in $^{99}C_n$ ways, where $n$ represents the number of additional numbers chosen.
Therefore, the total number of subsets with even products, accounting for each subset exactly once to avoid double counting, is given by:
$$\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^{99}\left(^{50}C_1\cdot{}^{99}C_n\right) $$

If a set contains both 2 and 4, you have counted it twice

The product of the elements of a subset $A$ is even if and only if $A$ does contain at least one even number. Therefore, you could count all the subsets of $S$ and remove the subsets made only of odd numbers. Since there are only 50 odd numbers in $S$, this should be $2^{100}-2^{50}$.

This should have been taken into account already, am I wrong? The empty set is counted both in the $2^{100}$ and in the $2^{50}$, so when you take the difference, you automatically exclude it.

You are still double counting. You are counting $\{2,4,6,8\}$ twice.
That is why, if you have problems where you have to count the number of things where "at least one" something needs to happen, it is better and more convenient to count the things that do not satisfy the restriction.
In your case, count the total number of non empty subsets, which is $2^{100}-1$, and subtract the number of nonempty ones having no even numbers, so that is $2^{50}-1$, giving the answer $\boxed{2^{100}-2^{50}}$.
Hope this helps. :)

I think I get what you mean , dividing by 2 isn't enough I need to divide by 4! in your example. The kind you do when you have n repetitions .

@Dhroov: A set of $n$ even elements is counted $n$ times. That approach is not efficient.
